# How do I display all the leap years between two year in javascript

Tags: javascript, leap-year

How do I create an HTML page which accepts user input into the text field as integer between 1900 and 2012. When the user presses the “Display” button, the function created in JavaScript should able to display all the leap year between the inputted integer and 2012.

**example:**

When user enters in "1970" in the text field then the result is:

```
1972
1976
1980
1984
1988
1992
1996
2000
2004
2008
```

I have code like this

```
var str = '';
var i;

for ( i = 1970; i < 2012; i += 1 ) {    
    if ( new Date( i, 1, 29 ).getMonth() === 1 ) {
        str += '<p>' + i + '</p>';
    }
}

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

I don't understand how to tie this function to the button?
​

Comment: What's the question? The posted code seems like it will do the job, but why not only test every fourth year starting from the closest year that is evenly divisible by 4?

Comment: @RobG The user want this to be executed when a button is clicked, but doesn't know how to to that. So I guess that the question is something like: "How do I get this code to run when I click a button?"

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to calculate what years a leap years in the [Gregorian Calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), introduced 1582. In the Gregorian calendar there are 97 leap years in 400 years.

Every year that is evenly divisible by 4, but not 100, but 400 is a leap year. 1600 and 2000 is, but not 1700, 1800, 1900.

Here is a solution that takes into account all the rules for leap years in the Gregorian calendar:

```
for (var i=1890; i < 2010; ++i) {
  if (!(i%4)&&(i%100)||!(i%400) ) console.log(i);
}
```

The rule can also be written as

```
( ( (year % 4) == 0) && ( (year % 100) !== 0)) || ( (year % 400) ==0)
```

To be able to bind this to a button you must put it inside a function:

```
function printLeapYears() {
   //Do your thing here
}
```

Then you must bind it to your button. For example

```
<button type="button" onclick="printLeapYears()">print leap years</button>
```

There are other ways to bind the function to the button. Since this is a homework question and I don't know if you are familiar with ids and `document.getElementById` yet, this solution will probably be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's an approach that just tests years divisible by four:

```
function getLeapYears(start, end) {
    var startYear = Math.ceil(start / 4) * 4;
    var endYear = Math.floor(end / 4) * 4;
    var leapYears = [];

    if (isNaN(startYear) || isNaN(endYear)) return ['Invalid input'];

    while (startYear <= endYear) {
      if ( startYear % 100 || !(startYear % 400)) {
        leapYears.push(startYear);
      }
      startYear += 4;
    }
    return leapYears.length? leapYears : ['None']; 
}
```

And here's one way (some might say not "best practice") to put it in a page:

```
Start year: <input id="i0"><br>
End year: <input id="i1"><br>
<button onclick="
  var start = document.getElementById('i0');
  var end = document.getElementById('i1');
  var el =  document.getElementById('s0');
  if (start && end && el) {
    el.innerHTML = getLeapYears(start.value, end.value).join('<br>');
  }
">List leapyears</button><br>

<span id="s0"></span>
```

Comment: sir, but sorry, how about if i just need one textbox and another is last range is 2012 :)

Comment: i want end year is not inputted, but have a valid number is 2012